# How to serve external Markdown files via Gitit wiki

Tags: git, markdown, wiki

I thought it was possible to link to external .md files from [Gitits'](https://github.com/jgm/gitit) wiki (.md) pages but it seems that whatever file I want to link to has to be committed in the Gitits' Git repo of wikidata directory.

Is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: If the files are served from another server, sure you can link to them like you can link to any external website. or what do you mean?

Comment: @mb21  

One way I'd like to do this is to symlink them somewhere to the `wikidata/` directory (since they could be on the same server) and then link to them by classic relative Markdown links.  

The other is just link to them by the HTML `<a>` tag in case they are completely outside the Gitit server. It is crucial that in neither of those cases the linked markdown is in the Gitits' VCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that out myself.

You just need to create a symlink to the file you want to show on the wiki and commit it to the `wikidata/` repo. That way Gitit will display the page with whatever content the symlink points to.

Also note that any change made to the content of the file/page through the wiki web interface **will** propagate to the linked file. **BUT** no commit will be made in either gitit or symlinked file repo (if that happened to be one); you'll just end up with edited file with no error shown.

**Edit**
There is still no way to render content, which is not reachable by symlinks. At least for now, as [this issue](https://github.com/jgm/gitit/issues/586) states.

Comment: Should I be able to create symlinks in the "static" directory and achieve the same thing, but without the danger of modifying the external files? I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Actually, I just tried symlinking from within the wikidata directory, and that isn't working either. Could you post some actual markdown showing how this works? Thanks!

Comment: So, I notice that if I symlink to an actual *.md file, as opposed to a directory, then clicking on the link causes that file to download, rather than render within the browser. Any thoughts on why this is happening?